# Extract with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table (incident) with a column (update_Action) that contains information. Among this information the names are enclosed in parenthesis.

```
06/01/15 09:49:17 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi): 
05/01/15 13:14:11 Tunisia (sabri.zayet): 
reset des TREs 05/01/15 09:38:50 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi): 
Pb persiste. Cdt,Hamed 02/01/15 14:37:45 Tunisia (khaled.rajhi): 
Restart cell Cdt, Khaled
```

**Question:**
my goal is to extract these names is to store them in another column (intervenants) in the same table.

```
update incident set intervenants=
    (substring(Update_Action,locate('(',Update_Action),locate(')',Update_Action)))
where Status='Closed'
```

But I got the following result: `(Hamed.Ghabi): 05/01/15 13:14:11 Tunisi`, instead of: `Hamed.Ghabi,Sabri.Zayet,Khaled.Rajhi`.

picture of the table: 
!`06/01/15 09:49:17 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
05/01/15 13:14:11 Tunisia (sabri.zayet):
reset des TREs
05/01/15 09:38:50 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
Pb persiste.
Cdt,Hamed
02/01/15 14:37:45 Tunisia (khaled.rajhi):
Restart cell
Cdt, Khaled`
`05/01/15 09:42:40 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
02/01/15 14:38:00 Tunisia (khaled.rajhi):
Restart cell
Cdt, Khaled`
`26/01/15 09:14:56 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
23/01/15 11:30:46 Tunisia (walid.hadjtaieb):
prière de vérifier l’état suite intervention maintenance.
il parait que le problème est résolu (en attache)
13/01/15 11:43:19 Tunisia (nabil.zarrad):
Merci d'attacher le résultat des mesures PIM sur SM9 (pour garder l'historique des actions).
12/01/15 16:35:10 Tunisia (fethi.nasri):
Résultat mesure PIM envoyé.
07/01/15 17:53:49 Tunisia (walid.hadjtaieb):
prière de planifier une mesure PIM sur S2
06/01/15 09:46:34 Tunisia (`

Comment: we need to see few of your sample data in table structure

Comment: Here is a field of "update_action" column of my table "incident":  06/01/15 09:49:17 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
05/01/15 13:14:11 Tunisia (sabri.zayet):
reset des TREs
05/01/15 09:38:50 Tunisia (Hamed.Ghabi):
Pb persiste.
Cdt,Hamed
02/01/15 14:37:45 Tunisia (khaled.rajhi):
Restart cell
Cdt, Khaled

Comment: Still not clear , try to give that in a tabular structure from `SELECT * from incident LIMIT 5;`

Comment: I do not know how to insert a picture so I added just a line of code below the column

Comment: Is all that from one row in your table?!

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQLite? Either way it seems you would need a function that cut out what is between the parenthesis, and return those values. This is because you have multiple parenthesis in the same text field.

Comment: yes Bria. i'am working with MySQL Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to extract the text in the parenthesis:

**EDIT:** removed an unnecessary variable + general cleanup.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `extractWordInParenthesis`(strIn varchar(500))
    RETURNS varchar(500)

BEGIN

    declare textString varchar(500) default strIn;
    declare extractedString varchar(500) default '';
    declare newOccurence varchar(500) default '';

    while length(textString) <> length(replace(textString,')',''))
     do
        set newOccurence = substr(textString,
            locate('(', textString)+1,
            locate(')', textString)-locate('(', textString)-1);

        -- check if the specific occurence have already been found
        if length(extractedString) = length(replace(extractedString,newOccurence,''))
         then
            set extractedString =
                concat(extractedString, ',', newOccurence);
         end if;

        set textString = substr(textString,locate(')', textString)+1);

     end while;

    RETURN substr(extractedString,2);

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

This would be called like:

```
select extractWordInParenthesis(Update_Action) from incident
    where Status = 'Closed';
```

And the update:

```
update incident set intervenants = extractWordInParenthesis(Update_Action)
    where Status = 'Closed';
```